# Вывод абсолютного пути к папке или файлу

Tags: c, unix

Как реализовать код на С, который будет выводить всегда абсолютный путь к папке или файлу а не относительный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция, которая вам нужна называется [realpath](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html).

Comment: Вот было бы интересно по реализации здесь что-то увидеть.

Comment: https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/a2f34833b1042d5d8eeb263b4cf4caaea138c4ad/stdlib/canonicalize.c